# Solving UIWebView deprecation warning by App Store on React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, uiwebview, app-store, wkwebview

I'm building a React Native app with Expo (SDK v35) and upon delivering the binaries to App Store Connect, I get a warning that many have gotten:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs.

I realize the warning is related to react-native-webview prior to v7.0.1 and that it will come up if UIWebView is used anywhere, including the dependencies.

However, I have cleaned up the code in its entirety, to the point that grep -r UIWebView ./* turns up empty (I even removed comments). I also ensured that all dependencies use a version of react-native-webview that is greater than the patched 7.0.1 version. Here's the log from `grep -r webview ./node_modules/*/package.json:`

`./node_modules/react-native-signature-canvas/package.json:    "react-native-webview": "^7.5.2"
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:  "_from": "react-native-webview@^7.5.2",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:  "_id": "react-native-webview@7.6.0",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:  "_location": "/react-native-webview",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:    "raw": "react-native-webview@^7.5.2",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:    "name": "react-native-webview",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:    "escapedName": "react-native-webview",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-webview/-/react-native-webview-7.6.0.tgz",
./node_modules/react-native-webview/package.json:  "_spec": "react-native-webview@^7.5.2"`

The only part of the app where WebView is actually used is through the module react-native-signature-canvas, which not only uses webview versions >= 7.5.2 but also passes `useWebKit={true}` as props, ensuring the use of `WKWebView`, not `UIWebView`.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the warning? Also, if I submit the app for review anyway, will it be rejected? Is the warning taken into consideration for review or will they simply test the app on an iOS version that does not support `UIWebView` and see if it runs normally?

Comment: I too am getting the same warning for Version 36. There seems to be also another reference using:
grep -r UIWebView node_modules/* Binary file node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler//ios/build/RNGestureHandler/Index/DataStore/v5/records/EJ/UIWebView In the doco for react-navigation, I think native-gesture-handler is needed for React Navigation to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Expo team has addressed this and a fix will be released in Expo SDK 37. More details found on this Github issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5497

The warning is given because the compiled app still has the `UIWebView` API inside it, even if the `useWebKit={true}` prop is set. Unfortunately Apple has just informed developers that they will no longer be accepting app submissions from April 2020 that use or have the `UIWebView` inside the application. In the meantime you can submit new and updated applications to the App Store until this hard deadline.

Comment: December 2020.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of app updates that use UIWebView APIs starting from December 2020.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `useWebKit={true}`, that is to say, you are using `WKWebView` not `UIWebView` at all. Then you can do the following to solve the problem -- Deprecated API Usage.

1. Remove `Libraries/RNCWebView.xcodeproj/RNCUIWebView.h、RNCUIWebView.m、RNCUIWebViewManager.h、RNCUIWebViewManager.m`
2. `Remove Libraries/React.xcodeproj/React/Views/RCTWebView.h、RCTWebView.m、RCTWebViewManager.h、RCTWebViewManager.m`

Now I have already uploaded app.ipa to AppStore successfully without any permission warnings.

That's all. I work for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you give a step by step on how to remove these libraries?